# How to import specific range of cells from Excel to datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to import a specific range of cells from Excel into a DataGridView in a Vb.net program. So the Excel range is A3 to C50. The names of my columns in my datagridview are:

- Column A is called `clmPartNumber`
- Column B is called `clmPartLength`
- Column C is called `clmQty`

I this possible?

Comment: Reference to import an excel to grid: http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_import.htm

Comment: That is not a Range I need to import a range of cells not the whole sheet.

Comment: You can definitely do this, I've been doing this for a lot of projects. Instead of directly using a databind, you manipulate each cell and add it manually to your datagrid since you want specific cells. You can manipulate and get each cell value using .NET.